# How to change server in PHP to access to DB?

Tags: php, sql-server, react-native

I have an internship where I developed a mobile application with React Native and PHP backend.

In my PHP file, I used to connect with SQL DB and get information (this is my file for example)

```
<?php
$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Ne","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
?>
```

As you see I'm using DB in local server (my computer); but now I need to depose my work in Enterprise server but I don't know how?
This an example of my react native file where I'm connecting with DB.

```
 return fetch('http://192.168.1.9:80/dcssmnt.php',{
   method:'post',
   header:{
   'Accept':'application/json',
   'Content-type' :'application/json'
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({})})
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
     if(responseJson=="null"){this.setState({ isLoading: true, isModalVisible:false, })}
     else {
            this.setState({
             isModalVisible:false,
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson,});}})
     .catch((error) =>{console.error(error);});
     this.setState({
     month:'',
     year:'',})
 }
```

Comment: _"now I need to depose my work in Entreprise server but Idon't know how"_ - What is the question here? How to connect to SQL on the enterprise server? How to move your PHP code? How to add PHP support to the enterprise server? How to configure the vhost? How to call it from your react code? Please clarify what you've tried and exactly where you're stuck. It's too vague and unspecific at the moment.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer, I need to know how to connect my php files with non local database (Entreprise DB in their server)